# How to fmt.Println() memory not allocated by the go program?

Tags: google-app-engine, pointers, go, google-app-engine-go

I’d like to print the virtual memory content of the current program from `0x10000` to `0x50000` *(an area containing a syscall trampoline on my system)*.

```
package main

import (
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)
func main() {
    syscall.Syscall(SYS_WRITE, uintptr(1), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(0x10000)), uintptr(0x40000))
}
```

However when I tried to compile I’m getting that error :

```
cannot convert 65536 (type int) to type unsafe.Pointer
```

In my case,`cgo` is disabled *(`import "C"` fails at compile time)*.
Also does `syscall.Syscall(SYS_WRITE` is the only way to do it ?

Comment: I am knew in golang. I know this is can be considered as out of bounds reads, but this is required to know if a particular system call is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert that address to a slice of bytes, which can then be passed to any `Write` method.

To convert the address `0x10000` to a slice of bytes with a length of `0x30000`, you would use

```
mem := (*[1 << 30]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(0x10000)))[:0x30000:0x30000]
```

If the size is always static, you could just set the array to the proper size to start

```
mem := (*[0x30000]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(0x10000)))[:]
```

Comment: What does the part`[1 << 30]byte`means ?

Comment: @user2284570: that's an array type with a size of `1<<30`

Comment: Is there a way to print that kind of array without the syscall package ?

Comment: @user2284570: You can't print _anything_ without the syscall package, because writing to a file descriptor requires a syscall. Or are you asking how to write the data to stdout/stderr without importing syscall yourself? e.g. `os.Stdout.Write(mem)`?

Comment: Yes, I need something that can be used with the`fmt`package. You should noticed that I was using the number`1`as file descriptor in my question.

Comment: A slice can be use with the format package, what is it you expect to see by printing the binary memory contents?

Comment: Hemmm thanks, finally it appears the unsafe package isn’t available`bad import "unsafe" in main.go`. This what I feared.

Comment: Is there a way without the `unsafe` `syscall` and `cgo` package ?

Comment: @user2284570: Go is a memory safe language, you can't read arbitrary memory without specifically using the unsafe package (or a syscall to do it for you)

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem you are facing is that you should convert 0x10000 directly to uintptr instead of through unsafe.Pointer. I don't know if fixing that will solve the rest of your problem or not.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to do it with `fmt.Printf()` or `syscall.Write()`instead of using `syscall.Syscall`directly ?

Comment: It looks like JimB's answer covers it.